# Xpages can't load, Error 500; java.util cannot be resolved

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I recently moved a couple of applications to a server that is running Domino 9.0.1FP8 (JVM version: JRE 1.8.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 amd64-64). Since I did this I've been unable to load any, but the most basic of Xpages.  I get the "Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception" page.

Via the ...IBM\Domino\data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\xpages_exec I get Exceptions such as:

- The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly    referenced from required .class files
- The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

I'm also getting the following Errors in the "Problems" tab in Designer:

- "The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
  find the class file for java.util.Comparator. Fix the build path then
  try building this project"
- "The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
  referenced from required .class files"

Is there a reason the java.util is failing in Java 1.8? Is there anything I can do? Thanks for any help.

Dan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code in a question.

Comment: Can you show error log from Domino\data\domino\workspace\logs\error-log-0.xml file?

Comment: @Toby those guidelines need updating to be appropriate to code running on other applications. StackOverflow has moved beyond just HTML and JavaScript. As a recognised champion on XPages, it's evident from the question code is not the problem here and this is pervasive issue at software platform level. Daniel has looked into and included the logs, which some do not, and they show no specific individual cause and indeed causes which shouldn't occur on the platform.

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs when Domino Designer 9.0.1 FP8 attempts to compile against a Java8 JRE. The version of eclipse in that Designer install does not know how to parse some of the runtime jar files in Java8. The workaround is to compile against a Java6 JRE instead. There were changes in the Domino Designer installation as part of SPR#BGLN9PXEVM to change the configuration of the preferences in Designer to point to a Java6 JRE instead of using the default JRE. If there was some install problem or you manually modified your preferences, you may need to manually re-apply the workaround as follows.

In Domino Designer, menu File, Preferences, Java, Installed JREs.
There should be 2 listed JVMs with paths like so:

- [x] jvm C:\Notes\jvm1.6\
- [ ] Notes 8.5.1 VM (locked) C:\Notes\jvm

If your entry named "jvm" is incorrectly pointing to the C:\Notes\jvm\ folder instead of the jvm1.6 folder, then you will need to edit it to point to the jvm1.6 folder instead.

On the Domino Designer team we are investigating potentially upgrading the eclipse version in Designer, so that it might be possible to compile against a Java8 JRE.

Comment: Ummm "Potentially" upgrading Eclipse for Designer?  I thought that was announced as locked in for the next Feature Pack 9?

Comment: Ok. The slides presented at conferences will reflect the public announcements, so trust those. I expect the eclipse upgrade to be in FP9, and the work is in progress, but I'm not using this forum to make public commitments, so I'll have disclaimers by default.

Comment: Ahhh ok.  Makes sense of course.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: FYI, as discussed at MWLUG, the eclipse upgrade is now proposed for 9.0.1FP10 (not FP9). See the current roadmap: https://twitter.com/darrenduke/status/895332649316659200

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the installer has not installed successfully. There's no reason `java.util` packages should be failing. I would recommend running the installer again, making sure all services are stopped prior to running it. That will ensure that anything that needs replacing isn't locked by another process.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I re-ran the installer and all the errors are gone. I appreciate the help.