# error 500 http web server: command not handled exception

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

[image: JVM ERROR]I think this topic a lot of ppl post it already. I also look for lot of thread in stack overflow and some ibm page. They do give some comment of how to solve this problem. But i still facing the same problem, it still give this error.

Case start :
Actually one of my customer, they have facing this error during running on webpages and also notes ~
**error 500 http web server: command not handled exception**

Action taken but not solve:

- The user id signing/creating the XPages allowed to run XPages in the
  server document?
- Do project clean, build automatically on designer
- Do testing on creating new xpages page with simple lable " hello world" , this one can run successfully only.
- Try to reload the http server by

tell http quit
load http

After do this the problem still same give the same error. May i know got any other way to solve it?
[image: Error Log][image: Error Log2]
[image: trace log]

Comment: I backup the customer database and run on local does not have any problem on opening it~

Comment: That issue can can be almost anything. Without code examples it is impossible to even start making suggestions.    Additional information is needed.  Have you looked at web log or error logs on the server?

Comment: HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs   , do you means this log file?

Comment: Install XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF which gives you easy access to the XPages log files. The log file will tell you the reason for the error 500.

Answer (score 3):

"Unresolved compilation errors: java.lang.String" points to a failed install as here. A class in java.lang or java.util should always be resolved. Ensure all services and any processes for Notes / Domino are stopped before the relevant install, jar files can get locked once used. [Xpages can't load, Error 500; java.util cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012987/xpages-cant-load-error-500-java-util-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: do restart whole domino server help? or must reinstall notes?

Comment: I would recommend re-running the installer. It sounds like it could not install some jar files properly. With FP8, this may be related to the complex relationship of Java 8 runtime on the server and Java 6 compiler in DDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012987/xpages-cant-load-error-500-java-util-cannot-be-resolved oddly similar

Comment: I've responded with a manual workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012987/xpages-cant-load-error-500-java-util-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: In Domino Designer, menu File, Preferences, Java, Installed JREs. There should be 2 listed JVMs with paths like so: [x] jvm C:\Notes\jvm1.6\ [ ] Notes 8.5.1 VM (locked) C:\Notes\jvm do you means this selection is enough to solve the problem? May i know reran installer means Java 8 runtime installer or Notes Installer? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Switch on "**Display XPage runtime error page**" in application's XSP Properties then you'll see a detailed error message which probably will lead you to the issue:

[image]

Comment: OK, now you see the error message with additional information. Please show us those.

Comment: ... and have a look at the log file on server, mentioned in error message.

Comment: Did you try a Project/Clean... in Designer? It recompiles all code.

Comment: May i know stackoverflow allow to upload XML file? error-log-0.xml as there have details information inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145078/discussion-between-desmond-sim-and-knut-herrmann).

Answer (score 0):

I frequently get this error when there is a mismatch/problem with access rights or the user login has expired and the app/database doesn't redirect to the login page. I suggest you double check the security basics first. (Might also explain why the app works locally, but not on the server).