# Notes (client) 9.0.1 FP8 CLPDN0031E: Event loop exception

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

This question is related to SO question [Xpages can't load, Error 500; java.util cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012987/xpages-cant-load-error-500-java-util-cannot-be-resolved) 
I am creating a new question because the answers on the last question to not fit.

First off, I have reinstalled Notes 9.0.1 followed by the FP8 more than three times. Each time I had one of two errors. The first issue was identical to the linked question. The second issue is what i am going to report now; manifesting in the inability to open script libraries. The help / log provides the following stack trace:

```
CLPDN0031E: Event loop exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.DominoDynamicColumnBuilder$DominoViewCustomizer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.server.util.DynamicClassLoaderVFS.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil.doClassLookups(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil.access$7(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil$BeanListMaintainerImpl.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil$BeanListMaintainerImpl.getManagedBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.project.DominoDesignerProject.getManagedBeanList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.design.js.ScriptLibScriptData.addObjectsToMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.scripting.data.AbstractScriptData.getPublishedObjects(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.javascript.serverExtension.ServerScriptingEditor.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.design.js.ScriptLibEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation$4.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.onMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.DominoDynamicColumnBuilder$DominoViewCustomizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more

Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.DominoDynamicColumnBuilder$DominoViewCustomizer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.server.util.DynamicClassLoaderVFS.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil.doClassLookups(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil.access$7(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil$BeanListMaintainerImpl.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ManagedBeanListUtil$BeanListMaintainerImpl.getManagedBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.project.DominoDesignerProject.getManagedBeanList(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.design.js.ScriptLibScriptData.addObjectsToMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.scripting.data.AbstractScriptData.getPublishedObjects(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.javascript.serverExtension.ServerScriptingEditor.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.design.js.ScriptLibEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation$4.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.onMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dynamicview.DominoDynamicColumnBuilder$DominoViewCustomizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more
```

First off, and related to the answer provided by Paul Withers: having run the installation packet about 4 or 5 times, I have yet to receive any error or hint that it did not install correctly or ran into errors.

Secondly, the JVMs are correctly configured as per the answer provided by Marie Kehoe.

How can I go about correcting this issue?

Comment: Running the installation multiple times doesn't help when you don't cleanup an installation before attempting the reinstall. The other boomer: Don't (never ever ever) install the Notes data directory anywhere below "Program Files". Resist doing a C:\Notes install (that are habits of times past). For a regular client use the "shared install" which puts the data directory into the user profile automatically. For Domino Designer you have to create that location manually... and suspend your AV while installing

Comment: of course I deleted the entire notes install  and data folders before reinstalling... I did not check if there were remnants elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same error when updating to FP8: When opening existing SSJS files the editor keeps blank, and exceptions are thrown in background which you can find in log trace.

This is already known by IBM -> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22000221

> "This problem affects only applications that contain a managed bean."

IBM give also a "workaround": you should  perform a full clean/rebuild of the application and then use the SSJS editor. **But note**: The problem may reoccur when the application is closed and then reopened.

Because this workaround doesn't work for us - and maybe also not for you - the solution was either to remove the managed beans from our project, or to downgrade back to FP7.

We chose the latter solution.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to comment author Per Henrik Lausten. He found out that since May 2017 IBM has a fix for this issue (Notes 9.0.1 Feature Pack 8 Interim Fix 1). See his link for more details.

We haven't try this yet, but this could be the actual solution!

Comment: yeah, that 'workaround' is a joke, and so is the solution of getting rid of the managed beans.  That is like curing the patient via decapitation. It looks like Im downgrading.

Comment: 9.0.1 FP8 IF1 fixes the SSJS editor problem. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963 for download options.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install FP8 interim fix 1 to fix the SSJS editor problem. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963 for download options.

Comment: Thanks!  Ill look into that next week